# How to make an inversely proportional loop?

Tags: c++, objective-c, c, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

Hey, I'm trying to write a loop which updates within a method at 1/60 fps.
Basically, im trying to find out how to write a loop that says:

If `x` is increasing. decrease `y`.

I tried defining two variables for `x`; `x1` and `x2`, `x1` being the original value and `x2` being the altered value.

```
int x1,x2,y;
x1 = x2;

if (x2 > x1){ y--;}
```

But this obviously cannot work because every 1/60fps `x1 == x2` and therefore the argument is invalid..
Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Oliver

EDIT:

So I have the distance of an object, which is `x`;
I also have the scale of the layer, which is `y`;

As the distance increases, I would like the scale of the layer to decrease.
As the distance decreases, I would like the scale of the layer to increase.

The practical application of this is, the distance between two objects increases, so the scale of the layer decreases thus zooming out, keeping both objects within the layers camera.

I simply dont know how to express this prog-matically.

Comment: if you want a loop why r u using if statement? Do you have ranges or count of x and y. if you have the ranges you can use for loop, if not you have to use while loop

Comment: A wild guess that this topic might aid your googling http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PID_controller#PID_controller_theory

Comment: Can you clarify a little more, perhaps with some data and how you want the variables to react?

Comment: Please see my edit;  
@ Shweta - Because the method updates 60 times every second. So the if statements effectively behave like loops.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This takes care of X increasing and decreasing.
I am assuming: integers, a 1-1 linear relationship.
(pseudo code)
Note, lastXValue is global or static to the context.

```
int y; // comes from somewhere
int lastXValue = y;

function callBack(int currentXValue) {
 int delta = currentXValue - lastXValue; // Note: can be negative
 lastXValue = currentXValue;
 y -= delta;
}
```

I am also making the assumption that the loop is initiated and controlled elsewhere and this function gets called from the loop.

Comment: Thank you,  
I did employ something similar to a callback function and got it working.

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to use a static variable to save state in between function calls. Read up on it at http://ee.hawaii.edu/~tep/EE160/Book/chap14/subsection2.1.1.6.html.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your edit:

> So I have the distance of an object,
>   which is `x`; I also have the scale of
>   the layer, which is `y`;
>
> As the distance increases, I would
>   like the scale of the layer to
>   decrease. As the distance decreases, I
>   would like the scale of the layer to
>   increase.

It sounds like what you *really* want is just to figure out a way to calculate `y` from `x`.  It would likely be this:

```
y = CONSTANT / x;
```

where you choose `CONSTANT` depending on the exact relationship you want the two variables to have - it's the value that `y` will have when `x == 1`.